# How to rename sequential files so they start from zero?

Tags: bash, rename

A non-elegant, non-flexible way of doing this would be something like this:

```
for path in *.jpg # IMG_1067_CR2.jpg, MG_1068_CR2.jpg, etc.
do
    mv "$path" "${index-0}.jpg"
    let index+=1
done
unset index
```

A much better way should support leading zeros (for example for `ffmpeg`), avoid tainting the environment with dummy variables, have a dry-run option (like `rename`), and should not require specifying the extension twice. Is this supported by existing tools?

Alternatively, how can I make [this solution](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bash-script-to-rename-renumber-files-785037/#post3842095) work with leading zeros:

```
rename -n 's/IMG_([0-9]*)\.jpg/$1/; $_="IMG_".($_-1067).".jpg"' *.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
rename -n 's/IMG_([0-9]*)\.jpg/$1/; $_="IMG_".substr("000" . ($_-1067), -4).".jpg"' *.jpg
```

which will render "0" as "0000" and "907" as "0907".

Comment: @l0b0: It's not `sed`, it's Perl.

Comment: @shil88: The difference appears to be that the OP's files started at 1067 and yours didn't. It's not a matter of not working, but simply accommodating a different set of data. You could leave out the `+0` and the surrounding parentheses, by the way.

Comment: many thanks for the clarification! now I understand the command and for some crazy reason your solution 'as is' works perfectly. (at the time it was "apparently" showing a random behavior... something strange on my end for sure!). I am removing my previous comment and keeping this.

Answer (score 1):

This will turn `IMG_1067_CR2.jpg, IMG_1068_CR2.jpg...` into `IMG_0_CR2.jpg, IMG_1_CR2.jpg ...`. Remove the `echo` if you are satisfied with the results

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for img in *.jpg; do
  echo mv "$img" "${img/_[[:digit:]]*_/_$((i++))_}"
done
unset i
```

If you want the change to be recursive to multiple levels of subdirs. You can easily accomplish this with **Bash 4.x** by doing the following:

1. Add the following line before the for-loop: `shopt -s globstar`
2. change `for img in *.jpg; do` to `for img in **/*.jpg; do`

Comment: I do believe `local` cannot be used outside of a function.

Answer (score 1):

to deal with leading zeros, you can use `printf`:

```
...
NEW=$(printf "%04d.jpg" $index)
mv "$path" "$NEW"
...
```